# Swift+Firestore - return from getDocument() function

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, combine

I'm currently dealing with this problem. I have Firestore database. My goal is to fill `friends` array with `User` entities after being fetched. I call `fetchFriends`, which fetches currently logged user, that has `friends` array in it (each item is ID of friend). `friends` array is then looped and each ID of friend is fetched and new entity `User` is made. I want to map this `friends` array to `friends` Published variable. What I did there does not work and I'm not able to come up with some solution.

Firestore DB

```
User
- name: String
- friends: [String]
```

User model

```swift
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {   
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String
    var photoURL: URL?
    
    var friends: [String]?
}
```

User ViewModel

```swift
@Published var friends = [User?]()

func fetchFriends(uid: String) {
    
    let userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
    
    userRef.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
        
        do {
            guard let user = try documentSnapshot?.data(as: User.self) else {
                return
            }
            
            self.friends = user.friends!.compactMap({ friendUid in
                
                self.fetchUserAndReturn(uid: friendUid) { friend in
                    return friend
                }
            })
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func fetchUserAndReturn(uid: String, callback:@escaping (User)->User) {
    let friendRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
    
    friendRef.getDocument { document, error in
        callback(try! document?.data(as: User.self) as! User)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly in this chain of events is it breaking? Put `print` statements everywhere and confirm that the document is actually downloaded, that the `User` object is actually initialized, that the array is actually looped, etc. Somewhere along the way, it will print incorrectly and let us know where that is.

Comment: @MJ-12 Great suggestion. I would also add a breakpoint and step through your code line by line, examining the vars along the way. Once you find one that isn't what you expect, update that question with what line it was and what the expected value was supposed to be.

Comment: Isn't the primary issue here that `self.friends` is expecting to get populated by repeating calls to `fetchUserAndReturn` which is *also* asynchronous (or, specifically, the `getDocument` function within it is) and won't return a `User` to the `compactMap` like expected?

Comment: on line ```self.fetchUserAndReturn``` I now get this error message: "Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'User??'"

Comment: @jnpdx this could be it. Do you have any idea how to make it work? I tried to append to the self.friends array each time i got a result back, but it worked wierdly in view (because of appending to the array I had to clear the self.friends each time new change was made in database and because of that, every reload of view cleared all the content first and then filled it with subviews - it didn’t look well)

Comment: It's tricky. You could try to use a `DispatchGroup` to batch everything together... I'd probably opt for rearchitecting things. If possible, get rid of the requirement to do a fetch on every user doc separately. If you can't, I might try appending each user individually from within `fetchUserAndReturn` rather than trying to set them all at once in your listener.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use DispatchGroups to group up the reading of the users but really, the code in the question is not that far off.

There really is no need for compactMap as user id's are unique and so are documentId's within the same collection so there shouldn't be an issue where there are duplicate userUid's as friends.

Using the user object in the question, here's how to populate the friends array

```
func fetchFriends(uid: String) {
    let userRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)
    userRef.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
        guard let user = try! documentSnapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return }

        user.friends!.forEach( { friendUid in
            self.fetchUserAndReturn(uid: friendUid, completion: { returnedFriend in
                self.friendsArray.append(returnedFriend)
            })
        })
    }
}

func fetchUserAndReturn(uid: String, completion: @escaping ( MyUser ) -> Void ) {
    let userDocument = self.db.collection("users").document(uid)
    userDocument.getDocument(completion: { document, error in
        guard let user = try! document?.data(as: User.self) else { return }
        completion(user)
    })
}
```

Note that I removed all the error checking for brevity so be sure to include checking for Firebase errors as well as nil objects.