# How to turn manual mapping to automatic mapping when fetching data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, codable

I have a function that fetches a user from FireStore. At the moment the function manually deals with the data. I want to change this using Codable. I have tried many functions but I cannot seem to get it to work. I think the code that is required is quite simple and short & I'm just not understanding something.

Here is the fetchUser function that needs to change to one that doesn't manually map the data:

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchUser(uid: String,completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel

    ref.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument { (doc, err) in
        guard let user = doc else{return}

        let username = user.data()?["username"] as? String ?? "No Username"
        let pic = user.data()?["imageurl"] as? String ?? "No image URL"
        let bio = user.data()?["bio"] as? String ?? "No bio"
        let uid = user.data()?["uid"] as? String ?? ""
        let isVerified = user.data()?["isVerified"] as? Bool ?? false

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(UserModel(username: username, pic: pic, bio: bio, uid: uid, isVerified: isVerified))
        }
    }
}
```

How do I change this function to manually map the data using Codable?

I want to do this because I want to implement another variable to the user model. This variable is favouriteItems.

Here is my UserModel

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserModel: Identifiable, Codable{
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username : String
    var pic : String
    var bio: String
    var uid : String
    var isVerified: Bool
    var favouriteItems: [FavouriteItems]
```

Code for FavouriteItem:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct FavouriteItems: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var item: Item
}
```

Code for Item:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase


struct Item: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var item_name: String
    var item_type: String
    var item_image: String
    var item_details: String
    var item_uid : String
    var didFavourite: Bool? = false
    var isFavourite: Bool = false  
}
```

Comment: have you searched for this at all? Like you did not find anything like
 here:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift
  and here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692011/swiftfirestore-return-from-getdocument-function  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I have searched for these and more. I cannot get it to work. I have searched for a long time on this. Clearly, there is no straightforward response which is why I have tried to ask a question about using codable in a clear way with a basic struct (UserModel) as this would be a helpful solution for others to work from.

Comment: I am also trying to find a solution for this (Using Codable to handle the mapping when fetching a user)

Comment: the  
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects gives you an example of using the `struct City: Codable { ...}` . Have you tried that? There is an additional link to `ViewController.swift`. Note, I believe that you should not have `@EnvironmentObject var sharedData: SharedDataModel` inside your function, `@EnvironmentObject` is for `Views`.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that however could not get that to work.

Comment: what errors do you get, and on what line?

Comment: can you show the complete code that you are using, not bits of one question and bits form another question, like what happened to ` var favouriteItems: [FavouriteItems]`? Show the code you are trying to use not what you think should be used, like the code above, is this the code that works or is it what you think would work?

Comment: I just added the code with comments.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach, is this what you have tried already?
Since I do not have your database, I cannot test this.

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchUser(uid: String, completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument(as: UserModel.self) { result in

        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            // A `UserModel` value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            print("UserModel: \(user)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(user)
            }
            
        case .failure(let error):
            // A `UserModel` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            print("Error decoding UserModel: \(error)")
            // handle errors todo
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: given your new info.

I see what is going on here, you have `UserModel` and nested inside is an array of `FavouriteItems`, etc...
But **you did not tell us** that your `FavouriteItems` (which shoud be singular) is in another part of the database.
That is why all answers tried to point you to mapping the simple model `UserModel` that you showed us at first.

To obtain your complete `UserModel`, you need to re-structure your database and your structs, so that you have
a `handle` on the different `DocumentReference`. So `UserModel` has a field of `DocumentReference` type, that points to the set of `FavouriteItems`, and in `FavouriteItems` a field with `DocumentReference` that points to the associated `Item`.

Have a look at my attempt to deal with nested documents, here: [Nested Struct with Document Reference in Swift Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73174143/nested-struct-with-document-reference-in-swift-firestore/73176017#73176017)

Note that since I do not have any access to the database, I cannot test any answers, I can only guess.

Comment: Yes this is what i tried. I get the errors: Cannot convert value of type 'UserModel.Type' to expected argument type 'FirestoreSource', Contextual closure type '(DocumentSnapshot?, Error?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body and Incorrect argument label in call (have 'as:_:', expected 'source:completion:'). All 3 of these errors are on the line:  let docRef = db.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument(as: UserModel.self) { result in

Comment: ha, I see what's going here, you already have asked this question before, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887041/swift-mapping-custom-object-using-codable  More info here: https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/ as mentioned before.

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I asked before! That's the guide I've been following the whole time whilst trying to get it to work. It's a great guide that is well laid out but I must be doing something wrong because i can't get it to work.

Comment: updated my answer with some explanations.

Comment: Ooooooh I see! I'm on the right path now! I'm new to firebase and thought references worked in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Add extinsion

```
extension DocumentSnapshot {
    func toObject<T: Decodable>() throws -> T {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data()!, options: [])
        let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
        
        return object
    }
}
```

confirm to decodable

```
struct UserModel:Decodable {
}
```

fetch user

```
func fetchUser(uid: String,completion: @escaping (UserModel?) -> ()){
        let ref = Firestore.firestore()
        ref.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument() { (doc, err) in
            guard err == nil else { completion(nil)
                return
            }
            guard let model: UserModel = try? doc!.toObject() else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            completion(model)
        }
    }
```

**Second Way**

user init with constructor as dict

```
struct UserModel {
    
    let uid:String
    let username:String
    let pic:String
    let bio:String
    let isVerified:Bool
    
    init?(value:[String:Any]) {
        guard let id = value["uid"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        uid = id
        username = value["username"] as? String ?? "No Username"
        pic = value["imageurl"] as? String ?? "No image URL"
        bio = value["bio"] as? String ?? "No bio"
        isVerified = value["isVerified"] as? Bool ?? false
    }
}
```

and fetch

```
func fetchUser(uid: String,completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> ()){

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Users").document(uid).getDocument { (doc, err) in
            guard let documentSnap = doc,err == nil else {return}
            if let value = documentSnap.data() ,
               let user = UserModel(value: value) {
                completion(user)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to do it in a way that doesn't use an initialiser. I don't get any errors when building the code however I get the error Thread 1: "Invalid type in JSON write (FIRTimestamp)" when it runs.